# Reusing countersink holes

Tags: repair, drywall, reuse

My son was hanging on the towel rack in the bathroom and tore it off the wall.  Is it possible to fill and rehang the towl rack in the same place.  I could move it down a few inches and hang into new drywall but then i have two white patches on a blue wall and dont have any touch up paint.

Comment: How was the rack originally attached, and what is the scope of damage caused by the pullout event?

Comment: Pic of damage and screw attachment part of towel rack would help a lot. Filling stripped holes, and replacing ripped out drywall are different projects.